# Should I continue to use str.replace over re.sub, if the string manipulation becomes "complicated"

Tags: python, regex, string

For example I have several thousand strings similar to:

```
zz='/cars-for-sale/vehicledetails.xhtml?dealerId=54222147&zip=90621&endYear=2015&location=Buena%2BPark%2BCA-90621&startYear=1981&dealerName=CarMax%2BBuena%2BPark&numRecords=100&searchRadius=10&listingId=389520333&Log=0'
```

I wish to truncate it such that

```
zz='/cars-for-sale/vehicledetails.xhtml?&listingId=389520333&Log=0'
```

I have two ways to accomplish this

```
zz.replace(zz[36:zz.strip('&Log=0').rfind('&')],'')
```

OR

```
re.sub('dealer.+Radius=10','',zz)
```

From a "good engineering practices" standpoint, which one is preferable? Readability vs. Maintainability vs. Speed

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: python2 replace takes `1.91 µs` vs `3.37 µs` for re, python 3 is `2.1µs` vs `2.4µs`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am using python2.7, sorry I did not include that. So I know that replace is faster than using regex, but if the replace manipulation is so complex-looking, is it still preferable?

Comment: From a "good engineering practices" standpoint, I would probably use `urlparse.urlparse()` and `urlparse.parse_qs()`... It would be slower though.

Comment: FWIW `spl = zz.rsplit("&",2)(zz[:36] + "&{}&{}".format(spl[-2], spl[-1]))` takes `1.17 µs` and `spl = zz.rsplit("&",2)
(zz[:36] + "&"+spl[-2]+"&" + spl[-1])` takes `935 ns`, but any version would break quite easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is difficult to answer because it is opinion-based. `str.replace` is definitely faster. Using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) in `ipython` with Python 3.4.2:

```
In []: %timeit zz.replace(zz[36:zz.strip('&Log=0').rfind('&')],'')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.04 µs per loop

In []: %timeit re.sub('dealer.+Radius=10','',zz)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.83 µs per loop
```

As `Padraic Cunningham` pointed out, the difference is even greater in Python 2:

```
In []: %timeit zz.replace(zz[36:zz.strip('&Log=0').rfind('&')],'')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2 µs per loop

In []: %timeit re.sub('dealer.+Radius=10','',zz)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.11 µs per loop
```

Which one is better depends on the program. Generally, for Python, readability is more important than speed (because the standard PEP 8 style is based on the [notion](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) that code is read more than written). If speed is vital for the program, the faster option `str.replace` would be better. Otherwise, the more readable option `re.sub` would be better.

#### EDIT

As `Anony-Mousse` pointed out, using `re.compile` instead is both *faster* **and** *more readable* than both. (You added that you're using Python 2, but I'll put the Python 3 test first to reflect the order of my other tests above.)

With Python 3:

```
In []: z_match = re.compile('dealer.+Radius=10')
In []: %timeit z_match.sub('', zz)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 µs per loop
```

With Python 2:

```
In []: z_match = re.compile('dealer.+Radius=10')
In []: %timeit z_match.sub('', zz)
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 µs per loop
```

Comment: How about regexps precompiled with re.compile, if you want speed?